# why is my mysql-proxy always doing selects on master?

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql

My selects are always going to master and if i stop master I got some 'Cannot connect, all backends are down.'

```
[read_query] 89.216.31.228:64166
current backend   = 0
client default db = nivo
client username   = remote
query             = SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' LIMIT 1
sending to backend : 172.30.1.149:3306
is_slave         : false
server default db: nivo
server username  : remote
in_trans        : false
in_calc_found   : false
COM_QUERY       : true
```

This is my start script:

```
MASTERDB=172.30.1.149
SLAVEDB01=172.30.1.150
ROOT_DIR=/usr/share

LUA_PATH="$ROOT_DIR/mysql-proxy/?.lua"
/usr/bin/mysql-proxy --daemon --proxy-backend-addresses=$MASTERDB:3306 --proxy-read-only-backend-addresses=$SLAVEDB01:3306 --proxy-lua-script=/usr/share/mysql-proxy/rw-splitting.lua --admin-username=adm --admin-password=pass --admin-lua-script=/usr/share/mysql-proxy/admin.lua --log-level=debug --log-use-syslog
```

When I stop master I got in log:

```
Cannot connect, all backends are down.
```

My server setups is this (this are all separate vps):

```
- mysql proxy server
- mysql master server
- mysql slave server
```

This is output of mysql-proxy --version

```
mysql-proxy 0.8.1
chassis: mysql-proxy 0.8.1
glib2: 2.30.1
libevent: 2.0.21-stable
LUA: Lua 5.1.4
package.path: /usr/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/?.lua
package.cpath: /usr/lib/mysql-proxy/lua/?.so
-- modules
admin: 0.8.1
proxy: 0.8.1
```

Can anyone help me where to start debug?
By the way, replication it self if working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `my.cnf` on SLAVE `bind-address=my_server_ip` (not lo ip).

And I added same user on SLAVE as on MASTER for select on some database like: `grant all on db.* ...` end so on.

Now splitting traffic is working 100% (so far).

So issue resolved.